# Command Line Parser Library - Select item from list

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

I work with the CommandLineParser Library. 
I'm displaying some groups in the output.

```
foreach (var item in DataViewModel.GroupModel.Groups)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(item.Groups);
}
```

Now i want to define some options, that i can select a group via input. Like:

Group1: -a

and display the name of the selected group in the output. 
For now this is okay. later I need to generate a csv from the selected group.

Here is the ObservableCollection of the Groups:

```
public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Thats how i set the list(with groups in it) to the ObservableCollection
the list groupList is from type IList

```
IList<Group> groupList = new List<Group>();
```

Thats how i set the list(with groups in it) to the ObservableCollection

```
this.Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(groupList);
```

Now: 
I'm showing the groups in the output.
What I want:
I Want somehow to select a group and save it to a property. It should be through an input of the user maybe -a "Groupname(or something like this)".

Comment: Ok. Do you also have a question?

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry.
I want to know how can I select a group?

Comment: Please show more code you used (the definition of the Groups array) and write a more clear question

Comment: @itay_421 hope now it's better.